# Will a dangerous amount of lead leach into soil from a galvanised corrugated steel raised bed?

Tags: metal, toxicity

I have searched, found similar questions but none answer my specific need.

I have built a raised garden bed to grow vegetables (ironically due to a high lead content in our garden soil - planning to put new, lead-free soil in the raised bed).

I used [galvanised corrugated steel panels](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Gibraltar-Building-Products-8-ft-Corrugated-Galvanized-Steel-29-Gauge-Roof-Panel-13478/202344567) for the sides. I believe any zinc leaching would be beneficial, not a hazard.

[image]

However, now I learn that the galvanising process often involves lead. When something is "hot-dipped", apparently adding lead to the process helps the zinc run off. My understanding is limited. A crude 3M home swab test indicates lead, possibly a high content (it went very dark red).
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot-dip_galvanization
https://galvanizeit.org/knowledgebase/article/why-is-lead-added-to-the-galvanizing-bath

My chemistry isn't very good, which is why I came to the experts. Here are my concerns:

1. How much lead would be likely to leach into the soil?
2. Would this lead be in a form that could be absorbed by lead-absorbing plants (e.g. lettuce)?
3. Would this lead be in a form that might endanger small children "helping" with the vegetables?
4. Would this lead be in a form that might be absorbed by the body when eating these vegetables, if not carefully washed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please provide a reference for how lead is associated with galvanization? The wikipedia article says nothing about lead contamination of the zinc, but it does say that acid rain may be a problem with outdoor galvanized steel. **Hypothetically**, if the zinc *did* contain lead at low or trace levels, then it will get into the soil as the zinc sacrifices itself to protect the steel it coats. Then the soil would be a problem. But you already have soil with elevated lead levels, if I read you right, so that is already an issue with kids because kids eat dirt.

Comment: @EdV - thank you, added some links to the "hot-dip" galvanising process. Planning to use new, lead-free soil in the raised bed, and mulch / cover the rest of the yard to lock in the lead.

Comment: If it was me (and it wouldn’t be since I couldn’t grow lichens on a rock), I would paint the panels, as per [Galvanization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galvanization) and lime the soil underneath your raised garden bed so calcium is in relative abundance relative to soil lead content.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the link! I had no idea that lead was deliberately added, especially nowadays when people go nuts about lead. The mulch idea is excellent, but adding lime is also an inexpensive additional step.